# Can a multi-meter be used to test home theater receiver speaker output?

Tags: electrical, home-theater, speakers

I have a Sony HT-CT150 that no longer outputs sounds.

Can I somehow use my mutli-meter to test the speaker output? Here's what it looks like
[image]

I want to make sure that the system is actually outputting sound, before I start ripping speaker wire out of my wall.

Comment: You have one or more speakers which are not outputting sound. Do *any* of the speakers output sound? If you have one speaker which is working then switch the speaker cable at the receiver and see what you get.

Comment: there is little that chance the in-wall wiring is the problem, unless a rat chewed it up or something they don't wear-out.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, flip the meter to "AC".  You should detect a fluctuating AC voltage when sound plays.  Some amplifiers also put a DC bias on speaker circuits, you can check for that too by flipping the meter to "DC".

Comment: you should advise to play a 60hz wave through the speaker when testing; not all meters will key in on audio frequencies correctly. also, some receivers are "smart" enough to not drive an unloaded line; to wit: if there's no speaker attached it won't output the right/full/any power.

Comment: I didn't mean to disconnect the speaker prior to measurement. If the amp actively searches for a speaker present and refuses to power up until it sees one, that would greatly complicate searching for a wiring problem vs. a speaker problem.   I presume that music will have a sufficiently wide range of frequencies that even a narrowband meter should register *something*.  I would be peeved if my meter presumed all AC was 50-60Hz. There is 400Hz on airplanes and quite a chorus of freqs on rail, amongst 25Hz power, block signaling, crossing detection and PTC.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check the connections from your amplifier to your speakers by using the resistance function on your multimeter to measure the resistance through the speaker wire and the speakers. It should be close to zero (mine was about five ohms). Anything very high indicates an open circuit and likely a disconnected wire somewhere.

This doesn't rule out a short between the wires though. To check that, you can take a AA or AAA battery and momentarily connect it to the speaker wire. If everything is connect right, you should get a pop or static noise at the speaker.

Comment: What you are referring to is testing the speaker itself. But OP wants to test _the speaker output of a receiver_.

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim Yes, this is how to test the speaker and the in-wall speaker wiring that the asker was considering *ripping out of the wall*. If the wiring and speaker work, then it is likely a problem with the receiver (by process of elimination).